# Git Python seems not work

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm begin in python and trying to use [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) and I desperately tries to make working this module.

I've seen on many website that documentation is poor and the example I follow doesn't seems to work.

I've try this on Windows (2012/ Python 3.5):

```
# -*-coding:Latin-1 -*

from git import *

path = ('C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Repos\\integration')
repo = Repo(path)
assert repo.bare == False

repo.commits()

os.system("pause")
```

And this on Linux (Debian/Python 2.7) :

```
from git import Repo

repo = Repo('/home/git/repos/target_repos')
assert repo.bare == False

repo.commits ()
```

But anyway, I've no result... And finish with this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gitrepo.py", line 6, in <module>
    repo.commits ()
AttributeError: 'Repo' object has no attribute 'commits'
```

in the two case.

My question is the following :

1. Is there a way to make this module work ? All the link I found are old...
2. If yes, please help me or giving me an example.
3. If not, is there another module ? I've trying to install Dulwich but no succes (on Windows only)
4. I've seen there is a way by using [fab](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/tutorial.html) ? Is it possible to manipulate git with that ?

The goal is to manage git with python in the future, as well as other things for integration.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What does `repo.head` get you?

Comment: when I put that `repo.head()` in my file.py, I get that `TypeError: 'HEAD' object is not callable` if that's your question ?

Comment: @minitech Does i have something else to configure before ?

Comment: It’s just `repo.head`. Not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module works fine, you're not using it properly.
If you want to access the commits in a git repository, use `Repo.iter_commits()`. The method `commits()` you're trying to use doesn't exist in `GitPython.Repo`. You can check the official module documentation [here](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for all supported operations and attributes.

See below for a working example

```
from git import Repo, Commit

path = "test_repository"

repo = Repo(path)

for commit in repo.iter_commits():
    print "Author: ", commit.author
    print "Summary: ", commit.summary
```

This shows the author and summary for every commit in the repository.
Check the `Commit` object's documentation for operations and accessing additional information they carry (e.g. the commit hash, date, etc.)

Comment: Ok. In fact, when i type the command with python -v, I've some results : with `repo.untracked_files` it show the untracked files. But with `repo.iter_commits()` it ouput something strange : `<generator object Commit._iter_from_process_or_stream at 0x0000000F94E4EDB0>`... I will work on the documentation.

Comment: Many thanks. It gives me a good starting example and working perfectly.

Comment: @mestra I recommend you to start learning python basics as well, e.g. work through tutorials. That might help prevent misunderstandings in future, and will help getting results faster with anything you try to accomplish in python.

Comment: @Byron I have already some base in Python, but when i've tryed to use Git-Python I was a little lost... the documentation is a bit hard to understand... maybe for a french like me ^^.